# Detect lengthy (line count) functions in my C source code

Tags: c, count, statistics, lines

I'd like to make statistics on the length (line count) of the functions I have in my code base, so that I can blame the guys responsible for the half dozen 1000+ lines functions I spotted.

Do you know how I could do that?

I know of `wc -l` , but I'd like to have specifics on internal functions.
I know also of `cloc`, but its stats are too generalistics.

Ideally, I'd like to present the result like this, not counting comments:

```
1 foo.c: 'do_work()' is 1534 lines long
2 bar.c: 'do_more()' is 451  lines long
3 baz.c: 'bloated()' is 2853 lines long
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sourcemonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) is a code metrics tool that supports C, among other languages. Looks promising, no first-hand experience though.